# Replace row when there is a primary key conflict while inserting JSON data from API to SQL Server using Python

Tags: python, sql, api

I have json data extracted using an API (`req_data` in below code) and I am trying to add this data a SQL Server table `[dbo].[test]` into the columns `[personid] (PK), [lastname], [firstname]`.

I wanted to add this batch wise so when i run this second time the full data repeats again and it throws error as the primary key values conflicts

Now what I want to achieve is two things :

1. Insert all values corresponding to the primary key `[personid]` if it does not exist in table - else update if the primary key already exists
2. Insert all values corresponding to primary key `[personid]` if it does not exist in table - else ignore if primary key already exists

My code:

```py
for item in req_data:
        personid = item['personid']
        lastname = item['lastname']
        firstname = item['firstname']
        email = item['email']
        cursor.execute("insert into [dbo].[test]([personid],[lastname], 
        [firstname]) values(?, ? ,?)", (personid,lastname,firstname))
cnxn.commit()
```

I have tried to using INSERT IGNORE, also REPLACE instead if IGNORE and it throws an error of - Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)

Comment: I haven't written SQL in a while. Are you sure those square brackets are supposed to be there?

Comment: well it doesn't make difference i believe

Comment: You definitely have a syntax error in that statement. If the square brackets are not an issue, maybe you shouldn't be wrapping all your values in a single tuple then.

Comment: There problem is not an execution part, i am very well able to run the code and get the data into my SQL tables. I just want to re-write the code so that when i run it second time it has to update the existing data and add the new data

Comment: In your first goal you are talking about an operation that is often referred to as an 'UPSERT' -- update if the record exists, insert if it doesn't. Given that you mention SQL Server, there's some great analysis on different approaches to UPSERTing here: https://michaeljswart.com/2017/07/sql-server-upsert-patterns-and-antipatterns/. Your second goal is reasonably achievable by simply `try except finally` logic. If you have a unique constraint on the column, then inserting should trigger an error, and you handle the error in a `try` block.

Comment: Note: if you can't create Stored Procedures on the server, and you have to solve this in Python, you could execute a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE person_id = ?` query first -- using an `if else` block, if it returns 0, perform an INSERT, if it returns 1 perform an UPDATE.

Comment: Or, again, you if you have a unique constraint on the column, try the INSERT, if it triggers a duplicate value error, perform an UPDATE in the `except` block.

Comment: i tried doing the delete and `insert cursor.execute("""
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[test] ([personid],[lastname],[firstname])
            VALUES (?, ? ,? )
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE [personid] = ?
            """, (personid,lastname,firstname,personid ))` not sure whats wrong in this code but it always throws this Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180) error